# in haskell type matching error

Tags: haskell

I'm using hugs to compile a simple Haskell function. But my function make type error
This is the Function:

```
expression :: Int -> Int -> Int
expression n d  = countN d 0 0 (div n 2)

countN :: Int->Int->Int->Int->Int
countN goal now max left 
=
if(left == 0 && max == goal) then 1
else if(left == 0) then 0
else if(max > goal || now>left) then 0
else if(now == 0) then countN(goal now+1 (if(now+1>max) then now+1 else max) left)
else countN(goal now+1 (if(now+1>max) then now+1 else max) left) + countN(goal now-1 max left-1)
```

It's the error :

```
 Type error in application
 *** Expression     : goal now
 *** Term           : goal
 *** Type           : Int
 *** Does not match : a -> b
```

Comment: A couple things: 1) Use GHC over Hugs.  Hugs has been deprecated for several years now and no development has occurred on it to keep it up to date, while GHC is very active.  You'll also get more informative error messages (even if they appear more complicated at first).  2) Use spaces over tabs.  You can _technically_ use tabs in Haskell source, but I see people posting questions with syntax errors all the time here because of tabs.  3) Most importantly, use guards here, not nested if-then-else statements.  It'll result in much cleaner code.  4) All those parentheses, you don't need them!

Comment: Also, you seem to have a lot of grouping problems due to parentheses.  Haskell doesn't use parens for function application, only for grouping operations, so something like `countN (goal now + 1 ..)` tells the compiler that `goal` is a function that takes the parameter `now` and returns an `Int`, which is incremented by one, which is then supposed to be a function that takes the arguments `if (now+1 > max then now+1 else max) left`, which are passed to the function `countN` as its single argument.  This error is due to syntax errors, nothing more.

Comment: I think you'd really rather having something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/1ea27df60fc9cdcc0f82).  I don't know for sure if that's the implementation you were going for, but it certainly is a lot more readable, doesn't overwrite the built-in `max` function (which is very useful in this case for replacing your in line if statements), and makes it look less like lisp by removing all those extra parens that are causing you problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this part of your code.

```
countN(goal now-1 max left-1)
```

haskell interprets this as ...

```
countN ((goal now) - (1 (max left)) - 1)
```

... which is clearly not what you meant, but haskell sees you trying to call `goal` with an argument of `now`. `goal`'s type is `Int`, but you're treating it as `a -> b` by attempting to apply arguments to it, hence the type error.

Remembering that whitspace is function application and operators have higher precedence that function applicaion, perhaps you meant this:

```
countN goal (now-1) max (left-1)
```

This would make your final expression this:

```
(countN goal (now+1) next left) + (countN goal (now-1) max (left-1))
    where next = if now+1 > max then now+1 else max
```